# Convert R data.frame to specific json file for heatmap concept

Tags: json, r

I have following data frame in R:

```
df <- data.frame(RowNames <- c("FirstCol","SecondCol","ThirdCol","FourthCol"),
                               FirstCol <- c(0.4,0.5,0.1,0.2),
                               SecondCol <- c(0.8,0.6,0.4,0.1),
                               ThirdCol <- c(0.7,0.1,0.2,0.6),
                               FourthCol <- c(0.5,0.3,0.1,0.9))
names(df) <- c("RowNames", "FirstCol", "SecondCol", "ThirdCol", "FourthCol")
```

And I like to convert this data frame into very specific json file for further heatmap drawing concept:

```
# desired output
{
  "x": [ "FirstCol", "SecondCol", "ThirdCol", "FourthCol" ],
  "y": [ "FourthCol", "ThirdCol", "SecondCol", "FirstCol" ],
  "z": [
    [ 0.2, 0.1, 0.6, 0.9 ],
    [ 0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1 ],
    [ 0.5, 0.6, 0.1, 0.3 ],
    [ 0.4, 0.8, 0.7, 0.5 ]]
}
```

Is there any specific approach, how to do that in the easiest way? I really have no idea where should I start. Thank you very much for any of your help in advance.

Comment: It is not clear how the 'z' values are selected. Perhaps `library(jsonlite);toJSON(list(names(df)[-1], rev(names(df)[-1]), unlist(df[-1], use.names=FALSE)))`

Comment: z values seem to be in opposit order for heatmap concept. So from the last row to the first.

Comment: and is there any way hot to add "x": and "y": and "z": before square brackets?

Comment: Just name the `list` i.e. `toJSON(list(x=names(df)[-1], y=rev(names(df)[-1]), z=unlist(df[-1], use.names=FALSE)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `toJSON` from `jsonlite` by placing the `names` and the data (reversed from last row to first row) in a named `list`.

```
library(jsonlite)
toJSON(list(x=names(df)[-1], y=rev(names(df)[-1]),  
         z=`dimnames<-`(as.matrix(df[nrow(df):1,-1]), NULL)))
{
 "x":["FirstCol","SecondCol","ThirdCol","FourthCol"],
 "y":["FourthCol","ThirdCol","SecondCol","FirstCol"],
 "z":[[0.2,0.1,0.6,0.9],
      [0.1,0.4,0.2,0.1],
      [0.5,0.6,0.1,0.3],
      [0.4,0.8,0.7,0.5]]
 }
```